# How to minify, bundle and then publish a TypeScript/React single-page web app project with Visual Studio CE 2019

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, bundling-and-minification

We have a single-page web app project setup in Visual Studio CE 2019 that is developed in TypeScript using React and LESS, and have been using the Publish feature of Visual Studio to publish to a folder that we then copy to our deployment site. We have a batch script that will re-build the project, perform the publishing, and then copies to published files to the deployment site, so everything is automatable from the command prompt.

Now, the project doesn't currently use any bundling or minification, but we're looking to add this.
The question is: how do you set this up nicely in Visual Studio CE 2019 (we're not using VS Code)?

Our index.html page contains this line for the main start point of the app (app.ts is the main file):

```
    <script src="scripts/require.js" data-main="scripts/app"></script>
```

We already tried a few things:

1. In the Project Settings under the TypeScript Build tab, you can set "Combine JavaScript output into file" to for example "scripts/app.js" and you end up with a single app.js file containing all your transpiled TypeScript code. When I run the app from Visual Studio, the app appears to work. 
   However, if I then do Build --> Publish to publish the site (which also copies all other relevant files, like 3rd party .js files, image assets, static files, favicon, etc...), then all .ts files still get transpiled to indiviual .js files which still get published to the output folder, so that's no good...
2. We also added the "Bundler & Minifier" extension by Mads Kristensen so we can get minification as well. So I added app.js as the single file to minify, and when we now build the project, we get 1 app.js file (bundled transpiled TypeScript code) and 1 app.min.js file (minified version of app.js).
   I then adjusted the last line in our index.html page to `<script src="scripts/require.js" data-main="scripts/app.min"></script>` to use the minified version app.min.js, but now the app doesn't seem to load nor run any longer...
   The bundleconfig.json file currently contains this:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "scripts/app.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "scripts/app.js"
    ]
  }
]
```

Has anyone managed to setup bundling & minification in Visual Studio CE 2019? Preferably in a way that the Publish functionality also works as expected?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: An alternative approach to consider as a fallback option if you don't find what you are looking for. Find a React/TypeScript project driven by `package.json` and `npm` (or `yarn`) which does (1) development builds without bundle compression/minification, (2) production builds with that, (3) copies/publishes the build artifacts including script bundles into some output destination. Then take all the `npm/yarn` commands that achieve all that and add those as VS2019 pre-build or post-build actions. Admittedly this approach won't let you use VS2019 to debug the development or production builds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @winwiz1 Yes, that's what we were thinking of as a fall-back: use external tools and hook them up via batch files in build actions. If we do this only for production builds, then debugging could still be done as we do now. Still hoping there is a more integrated way in Visual Studio itself (possibly via extensions)... But if you have specific tools in mind that you know work well as external tools, feel free to post some links.

Comment: This [project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/tree/master/client) I wrote is a part of the [solution](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) but can be used alone. You can copy its `./client` directory in another location, out of the solution. It will continue to work if you also copy along this [file](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/server/src/api/types/SampleTypes.ts).